# Error on mac OS Sierra in R: *** [depth.fd.o] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ddalpha’

Tags: r, macos, gcc, homebrew, gfortran

I had gotten these errors when I was installing libraries in Rstudio on a new Mac running Sierra:

```
Error: gfortran not found: *** [depth.fd.o] Error: Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ddalpha’
```

I could not proceed without downloading libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I didn't have gfortran, a part of the gcc compiler. There were other solutions out there, but I prefer to have my packages managed. I first installed Homebrew, which I did from terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I next installed gcc with Homebrew:

```
brew install gcc
```

I restarted Rstudio and solved my problem, even if R was giving some other errors.